# Rotate right in a BST using void

Tags: c++, rotation, binary-search-tree, void

I am not implementing an AVL tree but I need to create a method that would rotate the binary search tree to right, However, I used the following code and the solution is not working.

How do I implement the rotate right method including rotating the root node and the non-root node?

```
void BST<T>::rotate_right(Node* node)
{
    //Node * current = node;
    Node * move_up_node = node->left;
    
    if(node == nullptr || move_up_node == nullptr)
    {
       return;
    }
    else
    {
       node->left = move_up_node->right;        
       if(node->left != nullptr)
       {
           node->left->parent = node;
       }
        //set parent edge
       move_up_node->parent = node->parent;
                   
       if(node == root_)
       {
           root_ = move_up_node;
       }
       
       else if(node == node->parent->right)
       {
           node->parent->right = move_up_node;
       }
       else if (node == node->parent->left)
       {
           node->parent->left = move_up_node;
       }
        
       node->parent = move_up_node;
       move_up_node->right = node;
        //node = move_up_node;
    }
    
    // Correct height of ancestors of node
     fix_height(root_);
}
```

The rotate node input is 21
When I output it, it does not do anything.

Before I tested the function, the output was

```
 10 Height: 5
   R├──42 Height: 4
    |  R├──91 Height: 3
    |   |  L└──49 Height: 2
    |   |     R└──70 Height: 1
    |   |      |  R├──77 Height: 0
    |   |      |  L└──54 Height: 0
    |  L└──21 Height: 0
   L└──1 Height: 2
      R└──7 Height: 1
       |  L└──2 Height: 0
```

After I tested it, the output was

```
rotate node: 21
 10 Height: 5
   R├──42 Height: 4
    |  R├──91 Height: 3
    |   |  L└──49 Height: 2
    |   |     R└──70 Height: 1
    |   |      |  R├──77 Height: 0
    |   |      |  L└──54 Height: 0
    |  L└──21 Height: 0
   L└──1 Height: 2
      R└──7 Height: 1
       |  L└──2 Height: 0
```

Comment: Draw a subtree on paper and label its nodes. Now draw that tree rotated. Now label the left and right of each node in both trees. This will give you a very clear idea of how to implement the transformation.

Comment: You should either return the new root of the rotated subtree or pass in `Node**` so you can modify the Node pointer directly. Otherwise you would have to copy around `node->data` to keep the original root as the root of the rotated tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are these issues in the outer `else` block:

- `move_up_node->parent->right = node` is not right, as `move_up_node` is `node->left`, and so `move_up_node->parent` is `node`,  which means you actually set `node->right = node`, which creates a loop. What you really want here is `node->left->parent = node`
- `if(node == node->parent->right)` is not safe if you don't first verify `node` has a parent. So make this an `else if`.
- `node->right = move_up_node` is not right (it doesn't move that node **up** as the name suggests). It should be `node->parent->right = move_up_node`. The same mistake occurs in the next block.

Here is a correction of that outer `else` block:

```
        // Set edge between node and its current inner grandchild:
        node->left = move_up_node->right;
        if (node->left != nullptr) {
            node->left->parent = node;  // <---
        }
        // Set edge between parent of node and the node that moves up
        move_up_node->parent = node->parent;
        if(node == root_)
        {
            root_ = move_up_node;
        }
        else if(node == node->parent->right)  // <-- else!
        {
            node->parent->right = move_up_node; // <--
        }
        else // <-- no need for another `if`
        {
            node->parent->left = move_up_node; // <--
        }
        // Set edge between node and move_up_node (was OK):
        node->parent = move_up_node;
        move_up_node->right = node;
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me and it is showing an error. ` Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)` when I change it to `node->left->parent = node`.
`
 node->left = move_up_node->right;
       node->left->parent = node;
       move_up_node->parent = node->parent;
                   
       if(root_ == node)
       {
           root_ = move_up_node;
       }
       
       else if(node == node->parent->right)
       {
           node->p->right = move_up_node->right;
       }
       else
       {
           node->p->left = move_up_node->right;
       }
`

Comment: Removed one change that shouldn't have changed. Please try with updated code.

Comment: Now, I have managed to get it to function but it only works partially when using a random tree numbers.

Comment: If you have a case where it does not work, please provide that example in your question, and explain what goes wrong, so we can reproduce it. Obviously, the correct working not only depends on this function, but also on the code that builds the tree.

Comment: Hi, I have discovered the output of the case that is not working for rotate right.
 `72 Height: 3
   R├──78 Height: 2
    |  R└──86 Height: 1
    |   |  R└──100 Height: 0
   L└──11 Height: 2
      R└──33 Height: 1
       |  R├──36 Height: 0
       |  L└──23 Height: 0`

Comment: And the rotate node is 86.

Comment: It is hard to read that tree, but it looks like node 86 has no left child. Is that correct? And you say you call the function with node 86 as argument?

Comment: The comments does not allow me to put it in a new line when I paste, so I will add it onto another answer.

Comment: And yes, I do not think it has a left child.

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when there is no left child? Please don't post that as an answer. Edit your question and add the tree, the node you rotate and the tree how you expect it to be after the rotation.

Comment: Just to be clear: when the node that is to be rotated has no left child, nothing should happen. There is nothing to rotate. This is also what is in your initial code. If you think it should do something different, then please provide all necessary information in your question.

Comment: I have edited my own question and when I did some further testing in this bug, it does not do anything.

Comment: If you think it should change something to that tree then what do you think the output should have been? Can you add in your question what the expected result is? Just to repeat, if you specify a leaf node, there is nothing to rotate.

Comment: I just realised that if the rotate node does not have a left child, it should not rotate so I believe I am on a right track. What was confusing is those automated test cases that says passed on some rotate scenarios. Thank you for assisting me with this function. I thought it was a bug.